# Why does making this getter nullable cause a compile error?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

This code works:

```
class Example
{
    public Int32 Int32
    {
        get { return Int32.Parse("3"); }
    }
}
```

This code does not compile:

```
class Example
{
    public Int32? Int32
    {
        get { return Int32.Parse("3"); }
    }
}
```

> CS1061    'int?' does not contain a definition for 'Parse' and no extension method 'Parse' accepting a first argument of type 'int?' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

---

My example may look silly, but it makes a lot more sense if you use imagine an enum, like

```
public Choice? Choice { get { return Choice.One; } }
```

Comment: In second example `Int32` refer to property `Int32` not to type `System.Int32`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having property type name to be the same as property name is special case covered is specification:

> 7.6.4.1 Identical simple names and type names
>   In a member access of the form `E.I`, if `E` is a single identifier, and if the meaning of `E` as a *simple-name* (§7.6.2) is a constant, field, property, local variable, or parameter with the same type as the meaning of `E` as a *type-name* (§3.8), then both possible meanings of `E` are permitted. The two possible meanings of `E.I` are never ambiguous, since `I` must necessarily be a member of the type `E` in both cases. In other words, the rule simply permits access to the static members and nested types of `E` where a compile-time error would otherwise have occurred.

So, in your first snippet simple name `Int32` allowed to refer to property `Int32` as well as to type `Int32`.

In the second snippet that rule is not applied and simple name `Int32` refer only to property.

Comment: I am still not clear why in the first case, it doesn't refer to the property but in the second case it is.

Comment: @ehh Think if the return type were `object` instead of `Int32`. Then "Int32" would clearly refer to the property only and not the type. The nullable type is slightly more subtle, but it is still a different type, so the special case does not apply.

Answer (score 7):

In second example `Int32` refers to property `Int32` not to type `System.Int32`. And since the property `Int32` is of type `System.Nullable(System.Int32)`, it doesn't have a parse method.

You'll have to write,

```
public Int32? Int32
{
    get { return System.Int32.Parse("3"); }
}
```

Comment: When it is not nullable, the property `Int32` is of type `System.Int32`, which does have a parse method.

Comment: @default.kramer Having property type name be the same as property name is a special case covered in specification. In this case `Int32` refer to property and to type in the same time.

Comment: @PetSerAl if you can find the part of the spec, that would be a better answer.

Comment: @default.kramer *7.6.4.1 Identical simple names and type names*.

Comment: @PetSerAl I think you should post that as an answer.